# Regular expressions to match n digit number

Tags: regex

Could someone tell me what the regular expression would be to match:
number with `n` digits where `n` would be provided or `(` or `)`

Comment: What have you tried?  I don't understand the `or '(' or ')'` part of your quesiton.

Comment: So it should match an `n` digit number or `(` or `)`? This seems to be trivial and can be solved by reading a bit about regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: Is that `n` decimals/`(`/`)` (ie. parentheses count towards `n`), or `n` digits (ignoring any embedded parentheses)? I suggest providing some examples of strings which should match, and some that shouldn't.

Comment: Please almost try to clarify your question!! It's uncomprensible!

Comment: @webbi Joey, Polynomial and Rynkadink didn't have any problems and answered to this question.

Comment: Does not matter, because your question could mean a lot of different cases, if you look for help, almost try to be clear. It's just my opinion.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should work: `[0-9\(\)]+`

Answer (score 26):

Simple:

```
\(|\)|\d{n}
```

replace `n` with the number of digits you need. If you need to match a complete string, then put parentheses around the expression and prepend `^`  and append `$`.

Comment: This matches the parenthesis characters: `(` and `)`.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg: As per the question, yes.

Comment: Oh, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work for you. It matches strings with n numbers or strings like "(" or ")". Exmpl.: for n = 2 it matches strings like "12", "22" ....

```
^([0-9]{n})$|^([()]{1})$
```